# unable to convert JSon to StructField in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using below code to create a dataframe from json file but it's returning nulls for all columns.

```
schema = StructType([ StructField("time", TimestampType(), True) ,
                      StructField("customer", StringType(), True),
                      StructField("action", StringType(), True),
                      StructField("device", StringType(), True)])

#Creating Dataframe 
inputDF = (
            spark
           .read
           .schema(schema)
          .json(inputPath)
         )
inputDF = inputDF.dropna()
display(inputDF)
```

Comment: You will probably need to provide a sample of your data in order for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Don't use schema. Let spark infer schema. `spark.read.jso(input_file)`